# Why plupload library doesn't work in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, plupload

I'm using [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) library in my app. I'm able to click "Choose file" button and add files using Chrome and Firefox, but with IE8 when I click on 'Choose files' button nothing happens.

Here is my JS implementation

```
    var url = webAPIHost.toLowerCase().replace("api/", "") + 'FileUpload/FileHandler';
    var total_uploads = 0;
    var uploaded = 0;

     uploaderExpense = new plupload.Uploader({
            runtimes: 'html5,html4',
            browse_button: 'pickfiles', // you can pass in id...
            container: document.getElementById('fileupload'), // ... or DOM Element itself
            url: url,
            flash_swf_url: '../js/Moxie.swf',
            silverlight_xap_url: '../js/Moxie.xap',
            multipart_params: {
                "expenseDetailID": "",
                "fileID": ""
            },
            drop_element: 'dropzone',
            filters: {
                max_file_size: '10mb',
                mime_types: [
                    {title: "Image files",extensions: "jpg,gif,png"}, 
                    {title: "Zip files",extensions: "zip"}
                ]
            },

            init: {
                PostInit: function() {
                    document.getElementById('filelist').innerHTML = '';
                },

                FilesAdded: function(up, files) {
                    plupload.each(files, function(file) {
                        var filename = "";

                        if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) <= 9) {
                            filename = file.name;
                        }

                        document.getElementById('filelist').innerHTML += '<div id="' + file.id + '" class="uploadListItem"><span class="bf-delete-image" id="del' + file.id + '">X</span>' + filename + '<b></b></div>';

                        if (!$.browser.msie || parseInt($.browser.version, 10) >= 10) {
                            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                                showImagePreview(files[i]);
                            }
                        }

                    });
                    $('#isAttachedToDocWrap').hide();
                },
                FilesRemoved: function(up, file) {
                    if (up.files.length == 0) {
                        $('#isAttachedToDocWrap').show();
                    }
                },
                UploadProgress: function(up, file) {
                    document.getElementById(file.id).getElementsByTagName('b')[0].innerHTML = '<span>' + file.percent + "%</span>";
                },

                Error: function(up, err) {
                }
            }
        });
```

Here is HTML sections

```
<div id="filelist"></div>
<div id="fileupload" style="position: relative;">
  <input type="button" id="pickfiles" value="Choose File" style="width: 100px; position: relative; z-index: 1;">

  <div id="html5_18n9h5j961i36ravev1b7t1vm23_container" class="moxie-shim moxie-shim-html5" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 0;"><input id="html5_18n9h5j961i36ravev1b7t1vm23" type="file" style="font-size: 999px; opacity: 0; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;" multiple="" accept="image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png,application/zip"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see 'plupload library' created the div html5 container, which means the code is there but IE doesn't show it or open the file dialog. I don't know why?

Uploader library has an [example page](http://www.plupload.com/examples/) which works fine on IE. This means something not correct with the implementation

I can't put my hand on what is wrong here.

Comment: The example page uses the Flash and Silverlight runtimes before the HTML4 version, have you tried including flash or silverlight in your runtimes list. HTML5 runtime won't work in IE8 but flash should (and does in an application I made)

Comment: @RobQuincey I have changed runtimes to [runtimes: 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4',] but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I changed the runtimes to support flash and silverlight, like so `runtimes: 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4'`; It kind of worked. What I mean with that is, I have to click on 'Choose Files' button many times before dialog opens. it response very very slow.
It's a temporary solution for now since I'm working on my localhost.

while testing I ran into a security error. I found good information about IE8 and IE9 plupload's runtime [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14566769/66493).